# Making a bounded domain have volume one

Tags: geometry, partial-differential-equations

Let $U$ be a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$, which is let's say Lipschitz. It has measure $|U|$. Is it possible to "rescale" $\Omega$ so that it has measure 1?

This is because I have a Sobolev inequality that applies only to measure one sets and I want to see how it changes for different measures.

I think we can create $$\Omega_2 := \left\{ \frac{x}{|\Omega|} : x \in \Omega\right\}.$$
It seems that we should have $|\Omega_2|=1$ and also that we should be able to switch between integrals over $\Omega$ to an integral over $\Omega_2$.

But I don't know how to prove these two facts. Could someone help me?

Comment: I think you should rescale as $x/|\Omega|^{1/n}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the domain $U$ has measure $|U|$, then for each $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists a covering $\{I_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ of $U$ by $n$-cubes $I_i$ such that
$$
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \ell(I_i) < |U| + \varepsilon\,.
$$
Here $\ell(I_i)$ is the geometric measure of $I_i$, i.e. if $I_i = [a_{i}, b_{i}]^n$ then $\ell(I_i) = (b_{i} - a_{i})^n$.

Now define a new covering $\{cI_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ which consists of the same cubes but scaled by the constant $c$ (in every direction). Since $\{I_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ covers $U$, the cover $\{cI_i\}_{i \in \mathbb{N}}$ covers $cU = \{cx \; | \; x \in U\}$. We also have
$$
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \ell(cI_i) = \sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}} c^n \ell(I_i) < c^n(|U| + \varepsilon)\,.
$$
Thus $cU$ has measure at most $c^n |U|$. To show that we also have $|cU| \geq c^n |U|$, note that with the same reasoning we have $|c^{-1} c U| \leq c^{-n} |cU|$ and thus $|cU| \geq c^n |cU$.